# Can't play video URL in-line video in Edge or Chrome while playing direct URL works just fine

Tags: video, microsoft-edge

### Problem description

On many websites I cannot play streamed video when using Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome:

```
https://www.filmweb.pl/video/Zwiastun/Uniwersytet+Potworny+Zwiastun+nr+1+polski-29996
```

Instead of actually watching the content, I see never-ending loading indicator:

[image]

However, when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up DevTools, analyse the source code and try to dig down to the `<video>` HTML element:

[image]

Then I can copy URL that I find there, i.e.:

```
https://fwcdn.pl/video/trailer/uniwersytet_potworny_zwiastun_polski.vp9.480p.webm
```

Paste it to a new tab, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and... the movie is being played without any problems!

[image]

### Scope of problem

Problem occurs on many websites, including filmweb.pl, playnow.pl and many more.

I have performed my tests on following gears:

- Asus Vivobook 14 OLED with Windows 11 and Microsoft Edge
- Intel NUC 5i5RYH with Windows 10 and Edge + Chrome
- ThinkPad TP T550 with windows 10 and Edge + Chrome

For all three setups the situation is always the same. First link (to the website containing `<video>` HTML element) isn't working (never-ending spinner) while second link (bare URL pointing directly to `.webm` file on server) works and plays.

Mobile gear seems to be working just fine:

- Motorola Moto One with Android 10 and Google Chrome
- iPhone 2020 SE with Safari

On both devices both embed link and direct URL plays without any problems.

### An attempt to resolve

For first two devices I have noticed that both Windows 11 and Windows 10 are missing [Web Media Extensions](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/web-media-extensions/9N5TDP8VCMHS?hl=en-us&gl=US) and somebody (probably me) has uninstalled [Films & TV app](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/films-tv/9WZDNCRFJ3P2?hl=en-gb&gl=GB). I have installed both of them back to no avail.

I have also tried to carefully analyse <kbd>F12</kbd> console output. At first I have noticed an error saying that notifications are auto-disabled due to user not responding to them many time. I have thus enabled them along with disabling any tracking prevention:

[image]

After that console reports something that doesn't seems to be relevant:

- The resource  was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally
- Images loaded lazily and replaced with placeholders. Load events are deferred
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
- crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

But **none of them are pointing to `.webm` file** (the *.webm* phrase is not found in the entire log). In most cases these 404s and blockades are for .woff fonts, .svg images, analytics.js, ima3.js etc.

The only suspicious (?) things to me are lines in log file that points to:

- [ib.adnxs.com](http://stags.bluekai.com) URL
- [stags.bluekai.com](http://stags.bluekai.com) URL
- `generic:1` line
- `match:1` line
- `smart:1` line
- `getuid:1` line

### Question

What steps should I undertake (if any) in order to resolve this problem?

Comment: While you are at DevTools. What does it show in the Console? I bet there are some errors there. Also, you mention Edge, does it work in Chrome? And have you tried loading the same site in an Incognito/Private window in Edge?

Comment: @YisroelTech Thank you for your attempt to help. In couple of hours this question will be rewritten as I made a number of more tests today.

Comment: I do not have an answer for you, but to note that for me in Chrome on Windows 11 the embedded one works just fine.